# HTML contenteditable disable native rich text editing

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

I'm trying to make a **article** element editable by including the attribute `contenteditable`, which works fine. I'm able to type new text and style it without additional JS.

My problem is the native rich text editing, although is great for basic things like `<b>` or `<u>`, breaks some of my default formatting. When I hit <kbd>enter</kbd> the text shifts down [wrapping the new line of text in a new `<p>` tag], but then when I hit <kbd>backspace</kbd> as if to add it back to original paragraph, the native editor wraps the text in a `<span>` tag.

If this were just the case, I could deal with unnecessary span tags, but unfortunately the native editor *also* adds inline styling to the span tag, pulling the styles from the outer `contenteditable` element, so the tag would now look like this:

```
<span style="font-size: 1.5em; line-height: 1.3em;">
```

This presents a problem in itself when working with `em` units, as now the text within the `<span>` increases in size 1.5 times, not to mention the messed up line height. Therefor I would much rather have the article element contenteditable, but disable the default rich text editing capabilities and roll my own in JS.

In essence: **How do I allow an element to be *contenteditable*, but disable the native rich text editing functionality?**

I should also add that I'm working in Chrome, if this makes a difference. Does this happen with all browsers?

Comment: Regarding to your last question: no, that doesn't happen in all the browsers. It's a bug specific to Chrome (but you should test everything for yourself, testing in several browsers is a must to begin to understand if there's a bug in your code or in the browser)

Comment: So what features of a contenteditable element do you actually want?

Comment: You'll save a lot of time by using one of popular WYSIWYG components, such as CKEditor. When it comes to `contenteditable`, there are extremely many bugs and inconsistencies between browsers.

Comment: @TimDown to make the content... editable, but no rich text functionality (as I would add it myself)

Comment: So... why not properly styled `textarea`?

Comment: @Reinmar you can't create rich text styling inside a `textarea`